# Polish letters in NSString

Tags: objective-c, character-encoding, nsstring

I have simple question but can't find answer:

```
NSString *polishLetters = @"ąęćźż"; 
//How to get NSString *correctString = @"aeczz";
```

So it's about string coding..How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *polishLetters = @"ąęćźż";
NSMutableString *correctString = [polishLetters mutableCopy];
CFStringTransform((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)correctString, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, NO);
NSLog(@"%@", correctString);
// Output: aeczz
```

This is not really about "string coding". `ą` is Unicode U+0105 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH OGONEK), and the Unicode Data Base
http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.2.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt defines the properties of 
that character as

```
0105;LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH OGONEK;Ll;0;L;0061 0328;;;;N;LATIN SMALL LETTER A OGONEK;;0104;;0104
```

Field #6 (`0061 0328`) is the *decomposition* into `a` (U+0061) and "COMBINING OGONEK" (U+328). The above string transformation removes the combining mark, leaving just `a`.